# How to create proper formatted JSON file with BeautifulSoup scraped information?

Tags: python, for-loop, beautifulsoup

When I run this script...

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import json

url = "https://stock.adobe.com/search?k=interstellar%20movie"
page = requests.get(url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "lxml")

jfile = open('images.json', 'w')

title = soup.find('em', class_='gravel-text').text

for images in soup.find_all('div', class_='thumb-frame'):
    image = images.a['href']

    j = [{'title':title, 'image':image}]

    jstring = json.dumps(j)

    jfile.write(jstring)

jfile.close()
```

The problem that I'm having is that it creates multiple root elements with the title within every element.

Formatted output...

```
[
   {
      "title":"interstellar movie",
      "image":"https://stock.adobe.com/images/gargantua-galaxy-design-graphic-3d-illustration-red-wormhole-or-black-hole-shine-in-space-inspiration-from-interstellar-movie-night-sky-background/90184980"
   }
][
   {
      "title":"interstellar movie",
      "image":"https://stock.adobe.com/images/wanderlust-explorer-discovering-icelandic-natural-wonders/395993532"
   }
][
   {
      "title":"interstellar movie",
      "image":"https://stock.adobe.com/images/panoramic-beautiful-night-sky-and-star-abstract-background-elements-of-this-image-furnished-by-nasa/223412156"
   }
]
```

I've tried moving the j variable outside the loop and writing the title, but can't seem to figure out how to combine the looped variable with the other one. I'm trying to output the title only once with the list of links so the output becomes as such...

```
[{
    "title": "interstellar movie", 
    "image": [
        "https://stock.adobe.com/images/gargantua-galaxy-design-graphic-3d-illustration-red-wormhole-or-black-hole-shine-in-space-inspiration-from-interstellar-movie-night-sky-background/90184980",
        "https://stock.adobe.com/images/wanderlust-explorer-discovering-icelandic-natural-wonders/395993532",
        "https://stock.adobe.com/images/panoramic-beautiful-night-sky-and-star-abstract-background-elements-of-this-image-furnished-by-nasa/223412156"
    ]
}]
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

<sub>**Note: you shouldn't write to a json file in parts like your code is doing - that's not valid json.**</sub>

> I've tried moving the j variable outside the loop and writing the title, but can't seem to figure out how to combine the looped variable with the other one

Method 1: combine title and images after the loop

```py
title = soup.find('em', class_='gravel-text').text

imgLinks = []
for images in soup.find_all('div', class_='thumb-frame'):
    imgLinks.append(images.a['href']) 

j = [{'title':title, 'image':imgLinks}]
# dump j, write to and close jfile #
```

Method 2: initiate `j` before loop

```py
j = [{'title':soup.find('em', class_='gravel-text').text, 'image':[]}] 
for images in soup.find_all('div', class_='thumb-frame'):
    j['image'].append(images.a['href']) 

# dump j, write to and close jfile
```

Method 3: all in one statement

```py
url = "https://stock.adobe.com/search?k=interstellar%20movie"
page = requests.get(url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "lxml")


with open('images.json', 'w') as jfile:
    json.dump([{'title': soup.find('em', class_='gravel-text').text, 'image': [
        image.a['href'] for image in soup.find_all('div', class_='thumb-frame')
    ]}], jfile)
```

Method 4: what I consider the safes way to avoid raising errors [but don't use this if you *want* to raise errors when the site is in an unexpected/inconsistent format]

```py
url = "https://stock.adobe.com/search?k=interstellar%20movie"
page = requests.get(url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "lxml")


title = soup.find('em', class_='gravel-text')
title = '! MISSING TITLE !' if title is None else title.text

imgLinks = [
    image.select_one('a[href]').get('href') for image in 
    soup.select('div[class="thumb-frame"]:has(a[href])')
]

with open('images.json', 'w') as jfile:
    json.dump([{'title':title, 'image':imgLinks}], jfile)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this part `j = [{'title':title, 'image':image}]` in each for loop iteration. You are trying to write merged data without parsing over entire list

What you need to do is to merge state on each iteration & write once everything is parsed. For your desired output you want mapping between `title` and multiple `image`s - so you can use a [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)

```
data = {}
for images in soup.find_all('div', class_='thumb-frame'):
    image = images.a['href']
    if title in data:
        data[title].append(image)
    else
        data[title] = [image]

# Once all data is collated, format and write it out
# Using list and dict comprehension together to do the heavy lifting for you
formatted = [ {'title':title, 'image':images} for title,images in data.items() ]

with open('images.json', 'w') as out_json:
    json.dump(data, out_json)
```

Check out [list & dict comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement), as well as the [with statement to handle file I/O](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement)